# How many times the circuit need to run when i use get_stateVector in qiskit

Tags: qiskit, quantum-state, superposition

In qiskit,i use `get_statevector` method to get the statevector from my circuit.
What i want to know is how many times the circuit need to run.
Does is it only one?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you are simulating an ideal circuit or a noisy circuit. For ideal circuits, the number of `shots` shouldn't have any effect on the result.

On the other hand, the number of `shots` affects the result of simulating noisy circuits. According to the [official documentation](https://qiskit.org/ecosystem/aer/stubs/qiskit_aer.AerSimulator.html):

> For noisy simulations each shot samples a randomly sampled noisy circuit from the noise model.

Comment: So, for noisy circuits, does the computation run in the back for $\big($ `shots` $\times 2^n \big)$ times?